# Use Xcode to link my project into an existing repository in a higher directory

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git

I have a (bitbucket) repository.

I clone it locally to a folder `repository1`.

I create a subfolder `project1`.

I want to start a new project in Xcode, place it in the subfolder `repository1/project1`, and have Xcode link into the repository of the parent folder.

I want to do it in such a way that Xcode can push, commit, revert, etc. But note, that I might want to create another future project in `repository1/project2` under the same repository but a different Xcode project that needs to be able to function from Xcode as well, interacting with the remote repository if needed.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. You would have to decide how you reference repository1. This can be done either by using an Xcode workspace and adding project1 and repository1 to the workspace, or by making repository1 be a subproject of project1. A key element here is to not use hardcoded paths. Rather use relative paths. These paths will be all relative to the project1.

Later on, when you want to add project2, it is no different. Just follow similar steps. They all can co-exist just fine. I do this right now in fact.

Keep in mind the caveats to this are if you change directory structures, you will need to update your Xcode project. In this case, repository1 should be immune, but project1 would need to have the relative paths changed.

Note that an Xcode project is only going to look at the files you tell it. So the co-existence of subfolders project1 and project2 will have no effect on each other. Unless you tell Xcode to reference files in the other projects/subfolders.